# Initializing an array in the constructor then executing it in the main method

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

So I am trying to figure out how to create this constructor that allows me to make an array in within the constructor

```
public class knapsack {
    private int num[];

    knapsack(int [] numbers){
        this.num = numbers;
    }
```

now paying attention to the main file, I am trying to create an object that also allows me to use an array in it, like so:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        knapsack newKnapsack = new newKnapsack({40, 10, 46, 23, 22, 16, 27, 6});
```

however, I keep running into issues with the knapsack newKnapsack = new Knapsack line. I am not sure if this is how you create a constructor to create an array and store it.

I am very new to java, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can construct an instance of the class using the `new` keyword followed by **class name**, not the variable name. In your case it should be `knapsack newKnapsack = new knapsack({ ...`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating the object you are not calling to the constructor in here. Also the way you have created the array is wrong. This is the correct way to create it,

```
public class Knapsack {
    private int num[];

    Knapsack(int[] numbers) {
        this.num = numbers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Knapsack newKnapsack = new Knapsack(new int[]{40, 10, 46, 23, 22, 16, 27, 6});

        for (int i = 0; i < newKnapsack.num.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(newKnapsack.num[i]);
        }

        Knapsack.bestTwoValues(newKnapsack.num, 1); //you can access only static members by calling like this
        newKnapsack.bestTwoValues(newKnapsack.num, 1); //this way you can access both static and instance variables
    }

    static int bestTwoValues(int numbers[], int target) {
        //your code
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Also please try to follow camel notation when you writing code. So in here `class` name should be `Knapsack` instead of `knapsack`

Comment: So when you are creating the object, you must add the same parameters that you created in the constructor, correct?

Comment: Also when you are trying to print out a method that you created in the Knapsack class in the main method, how would you be able to do that?

Comment: Yes you have to add the same parameters as you declared in the constructor. You mean print out the array?

Comment: I have the method named bestTwoValues, so and in that method it basically given an array of numbers, it finds 2 numbers, and when added together, it comes close to but doesn't exceed the specified target values.

Comment: so it has.                                                                                                              static int bestTwoValues(int numbers[], int target).                                                         and I want to be able to use this method in the main method that we had created an object in, so how would I be able to call upon it? like Knapsack.bestTwoValues()?

Comment: You can do it in two ways. Since its a static method, you can dirrectly acces it like this, knapsack.bestTwoValues(newKnapsack.num, 1); this way works if it is only a static method. Other way is newKnapsack.bestTwoValues(newKnapsack.num, 1); this works for both instance and static method. I have added 1 as the target parameter in here

Comment: For static members you can directly access by calling YourClassName.yourMember without creating an instance. Member can be a variable or a method.

Comment: @Marytaco I have updated the code. Please a take a look at it

Comment: wow thank you so much! so the point of the for loop is just to print out the numbers that we had placed in the newKapsack array?